# Pandas: if last non-zero value < 0: replace with 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,-2,0,0], 'B': [0, 0, 0, 3, -2], 'C' : [0, 0, -2, 4, 0], 'D': [0, -3, 2, 1, -2]} ) 

Out: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  2  0  0 -3
2 -2  0 -2  2
3  0  3  4  1
4  0 -2  0 -2
```

For each **column**, if the **last non-zero** value < 0 : repace it with 0.

expected result:

```py
df_end = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,0,0,0], 'B': [0, 0, 0, 3, 0], 'C' : [0, 0, -2, 4, 0], 'D': [0, -3, 2, 1, 0]} ) 
df_end

Out: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  2  0  0 -3
2  0  0 -2  2
3  0  3  4  1
4  0  0  0  0
```

I have solved the opposite problem (if **first non-zero** value < 0, replace with 0)  with :

```py
df.where(df.gt(0).cummax(),0)
```

I now need it to look at the table from the bottom.

#EDIT
As was pointed out in the comments, df.where(df.gt(0).cummax(),0) will eliminate all - values until the first positive. In my original Dataframe Positive and negative values always alternate, so df.where(df.gt(0).cummax(),0) works. I made a bad example dataframe.

Comment: Do you mean for each column?

Comment: Yes, for each column iterate from the bottom up, if the first non-zero value <0, repalce it with 0.

Comment: I have the feeling that the method you give would replace more than just the *first non-zero* value < 0. like in the column C, if you replace by [0, -1, -2, 4, 0], then -1 and -2 would be replaced by 0, not only -1?

Comment: @Ben.T same here ~

Comment: @Ben.T, Yeah i made a mistake in writing the example: in my original dataframe the positive and negative values always alternate (buy-sell positions). I just want to make sure that the first position is a buy (since i cannot sell if i don't have)- and the last is a sell. I made a bad example dataframe !

Comment: @David8 if values are always alternated, then all good :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try `iloc[::-1]` to revert `df`:

```
df[~df.iloc[::-1].gt(0).cummax()] = 0
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  2  0  0 -3
2  0  0 -2  2
3  0  3  4  1
4  0  0  0  0
```

---

**Update**: As @Ben.T commented, in the case you have several negative endings, the above would turn them all into zero. This would fix that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,-2,-1,0], 'B': [0, 0, 0, 3, -2], 'C' : [0, 0, -2, 4, 0], 'D': [0, -3, 2, 1, -2]} ) 

s = df.iloc[::-1]
df[s.lt(0).cumsum().eq(1) & (~s.gt(0).cummax())] = 0
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  2  0  0 -3
2 -2  0 -2  2
3  0  3  4  1
4  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only replace the last negative value to 0

```
s=np.sign(df).iloc[::-1].eq(-1).idxmax()
df.values[s,df.columns.get_indexer(s.index)]=0
df
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  2  0  0 -3
2  0  0  0  2
3  0  3  4  1
4  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: i only want to replace the negative value when the last non-zero value < 0 (first counting from the bottom) -  if the last non-zero value > 0, i dont want to replace anything.